# How do I stop my script from writing the last row of a Panda dataframe multiple times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, while-loop

My app is relatively simple as it tracks a user's idle time if the user has been idle for more than .5 seconds, prints it to stdout (for debugging in Pycharm), creates a Pandas dataframe, and then once the mouse is moved, it writes the last idle time to a csv file.

The kicker is that the resulting CSV shows duplicates of what I have determined to be the last row of the dataframe. So essentially, what I have determined is that if I keep moving the mouse, it just continues to write that last row.

How can I get the script to write the last row only once, once I go from being idle to active, then have the loop resume once I go back to idle and then repeat the process? I tried to remove the last row, `df.head(-1)` but that didn't do anything. FYI, I'm a Python n00b, so any help would be **greatly** appreciated and a learning opportunity for me.

```
class LASTINPUTINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('cbSize', c_uint),
        ('dwTime', c_uint),
    ]


def main():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        if track_idle_time() >= .5:
            print(track_idle_time())
            df = pd.DataFrame({track_idle_time()})
            print(df.values)
        if track_idle_time() < .5:
            df.head(-1)
            df.to_csv(r'C:\users\bob\Desktop\activity.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
        else:
            track_idle_time()

def track_idle_time():
    lastInputInfo = LASTINPUTINFO()
    lastInputInfo.cbSize = sizeof(lastInputInfo)
    windll.user32.GetLastInputInfo(byref(lastInputInfo))
    millis = windll.kernel32.GetTickCount() - lastInputInfo.dwTime
    return millis / 1000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

So, one thing I notice is that you are calling `track_idle_time()` lots of times - if the last input time doesn't change between these calls, there's no need, and if it ever *does*, you're risking incorrect behavior. This isn't what causes your problem, but it's still better to clean this up.

What actually does cause your problem is that you *set* your DF whenever the idle time exceeds >.5, but you *write* it whenever it's <.5. As long as the idle time stays below <.5, you're going to keep writing the last time it was >.5. Just clear it after writing.

(Btw, I'm not sure why you're using a DataFrame here even though it seems you're just writing a single number, but I guess maybe you want to add more columns later.)

```
df = None # initialize

while True:
    idle_time = track_idle_time()
    if idle_time >= .5:
        #print(idle_time)
        df = pd.DataFrame({idle_time})
        #print(df.values)
    elif df != None:
        df.to_csv(r'C:\users\bob\Desktop\activity.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)
        df = None # clear after writing
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks so much Christoph. I understand what you've done here, but I am getting the following: `ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` It's happening at `elif df:`

Comment: Oh, sorry; I should've used `df != None` there. I forgot that dataframes can't just be coerced to boolean the way a Python list can.

Comment: It still won't work. As soon as I move the mouse, I get the error again.

Comment: I added `elif not df.empty` and it works for a short bit. After a couple writes (by me moving my mouse, letting it go idle, and then moving my mouse again), it returns the error, `AttributeError: 'NoneType object has no attribute 'empty'` which tells me that the DF is empty. But I don't understand why it would be empty if it's constantly running the loop.

Comment: Fixed. Clear the dataframe by using `df = pd.DataFrame()` rather than `df = None`